# Issue persisting objects in Glassfish 4 with JPA - Object: is not a known Entity type

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, persistence, glassfish-4.1

I am using Glassfish 4.1.1 and MySQL. I have a table named customer and a class named Customer. When I use JSF and a controller to persist newly entered customer data I get the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: model.Customer@e5202 is not a known Entity type.`I checked other posts that hat the same error message but I have all the annotations and entries in the persistence.xml that helped others . Help greatly appreciated since I've been stuck on this for quite a while.

my Customer class that I essentially generated from Mysql via the Eclipsa JPA Wizard goes like this:

```
@Entity
@Model
@NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
```

In the controller where the error occurs the code is this:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="customerController")
public class CustomerController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject 
    private Customer customer;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction ut;

    public String save(){

        try{
            ut.begin();
            em.persist(customer);
            ut.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Shop");
            log.logp(Level.SEVERE, this.getClass().toString(), "save()", "customer could not be persisted.", e);
        }
```

My persistance.xml goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PrintCenterAdmin" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- some classes included-->
        <class>model.Customer</class>


        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here the full blown stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: model.Customer@4b4638 is not a known Entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at controllers.CustomerController.save(CustomerController.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I guess that you're mixing up 2 different transaction types in your application : _JTA_ & _RESOURCE_LOCAL_. In your persistence xml, you've declared transaction-type as JTA, which means that transactions are managed by container (glassfish). But in your controller, you're actually managing the transactions yourself using `UserTransaction`, which belong to _RESOURCE_LOCAL_ type.

Comment: Actually I first had omitted the transaction. However the system complained requiring a transaction. To what I read this is because I am invoking persist not in a session bean but in a controller and in this context the container does not manage it automatically. So this should be fine

Comment: Btw. if I try to persist a customer from a session bean everything works perfect and I can see the new rows in the db.

Comment: I found that if I use EntityManager as above without transaction I get javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
 at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:161) ... However if I use an EntityManagerFactory and call emf.createEntityManager().persist(customer) I do not get that error but the error I get when I use EntityManager with transaction, i.e. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: model.Customer@b3228e is not a known Entity type.